# Export constructor and enum in an npm package

Tags: javascript, npm

I haven't got much experience with NPM or Node.js, my JavaScript work is mainly limited to web browsers. I've written a JavaScript library that provides two things: 1. a constructor function, and 2. an enum type.

Of course there are no real "enums" in JavaScript, so my JS file basically looks like this:

```js
function MyClass() {
    // Implementation
    this.doWork = function () {
        // ...
        return MyEnum.Success;
    };
}

var MyEnum = {
    Error: 0,
    Success: 1,
    Something: 2,
    More: 3
    // etc.
    // I could probably use Object.define here to make it constant
};
```

The `MyClass` function uses properties from `MyEnum` internally and `MyEnum` is also useful for the caller of `MyClass`. So it should remain public.

Now an npm package can only export either properties in the main object, or the object itself. I could do these things:

```js
module.exports = MyClass;
```

Or

```js
module.exports = {
    MyClass: MyClass,
    MyEnum: MyEnum
};
```

In the first case, it's easy to use the class directly but `MyEnum` gets lost.

```js
let MyClass = require("myclass");
let x = new MyClass();
// Where is MyEnum?
```

The second variant needs the class name written twice when using it.

```js
let MyClass = require("myclass");
let x = new MyClass.MyClass();
if (x.doWork() === MyClass.MyEnum.Success) { }
```

What can I do to solve this problem and make the constructor available directly as it seems to be normal, and also export the enum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make the enum a property of the function object?

```
// myclass.js
// ...
MyClass.MyEnum = MyEnum;
module.exports = MyClass;

// elsewhere.js
let MyClass = require("myclass");
let x = new MyClass();
if (x.doWork() === MyClass.MyEnum.Success) { }
```